# Unattended Upgrades failing

Tags: debian, apt, unattended-upgrades

I keep getting this error on apt-get upgrade:

```
Installing unattended-upgrades (0.93.1+nmu1) ...
Failed to start unattended-upgrades.service: Unit unattended-upgrades.service failed to load: Invalid argument. See system logs and 'systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript unattended-upgrades, action "start" failed.
● unattended-upgrades.service - Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:unattended-upgrade(8)

jun 06 18:29:32 PRODUCTION systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
jun 06 18:29:32 PRODUCTION systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
jun 06 18:29:32 PRODUCTION systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
jun 06 18:32:41 PRODUCTION systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
jun 06 18:32:41 PRODUCTION systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
jun 06 18:32:41 PRODUCTION systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
jun 06 18:32:41 PRODUCTION systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
jun 06 18:33:24 PRODUCTION systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
jun 06 18:33:24 PRODUCTION systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
jun 06 18:33:24 PRODUCTION systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 subprocesso script post-installation returned exit status code 6
Errors were found while processing:
 unattended-upgrades
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't care about unattended-upgrades, it can be removed. I tried apt-get remove but no luck there:

```
Removing unattended-upgrades (0.93.1+nmu1) ...
Failed to stop unattended-upgrades.service: Unit unattended-upgrades.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript unattended-upgrades, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--remove):
 subprocess script pre-removal returned exit status error 5
Errors were found while processing:
 unattended-upgrades
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The messages have been translated as some of them were not in english.

I have debian jessie with sid repository configured.

uname -a:
`Linux PRODUCTION 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2 (2017-04-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

cat /etc/debian_version:
`9.0`

I just want that nasty error gone, I don't care how. either by removing the package or fixing the issue, but I don't seem to be able to remove it, nor am I able to fix it due to lack of knowledge :)

Any hint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
systemctl mask unattended-upgrades
```

Explanation:

systemd units can be overridden by the adminstrator putting a file with the same name in `/etc/systemd/system`.

This mechanism can also be used to "mask" a service from being activated by socket activation, manual starts, or any other method.  Instead of creating a file with the same name, if there is a symbolic link to `/dev/null`, then the unit is effectively ignored.

So you can ab(use) `systemctl mask`, to replace the contents of the unit with nothing.

To avoid the possibility confusion in future, check that you remove the mask once you have removed the package.  `systemctl unmask unattended-upgrades`.

Comment: spot on! may the force be with you :)

Comment: I tried doing it carefully, by adding `--runtime` switch. This makes the change temporary. Then turned off the service using `sysv-rc-conf`. Seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this problem, and it seems that the cause of this is that systemd is too old to support the `unattended-upgrades.service` file which omits the `ExecStart` configuration. Make sure that the `systemd` package is also upgraded (version 232 worked for me).

If the problem persists (as it did for me), then `systemd` might not have been restarted during the upgrade (I think it should happen automatically, but I think it didn't for me). To fix that, run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reexec
```

This restarts `systemd`, running the newer version which should support the new service file just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on Debian 9 with latest systemd and unattended-upgrade packages. So I edited this file:

```
/lib/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service
```

and add this line:

```
ExecStart=/bin/true
```

just before ExecStop line and everything is ok now while service is not masked.

Comment: Thanks for writing your experience! It would be better not to edit a packaged file in `/lib`, because it will be overwritten by any package updates. Instead you could create a file `/etc/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service.d/override.conf` with two lines, `[Service]` and `ExecStart=/bin/true`.  (Or more conveniently, use `systemctl edit unattended-upgrades`).  And if this problem is still occurring, you might wish to [report the bug to Debian](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting)

Comment: Yeah. you are right! even using `systemd mask` command  is better solution for such this things.